# urxvt transparent cursor

Tags: xorg, terminal, rxvt, cursor

I've changed my `.Xdefaults` for a black background, white foreground, but my cursor is now opaque. I can't see the letter I'm over, and worse I can't see my screen hardstatus.

Google is just pulling up how to make the whole term transparent.

How can I make my cursor transparent again?

```
$ cat .Xdefaults
URxvt*transparent: true
URxvt*tintColor: Black
URxvt*shading: 110
URxvt*saveLines: 60000
URxvt*foreground: White
URxvt*font: xft:Droid Sans Mono:pixelsize=14
URxvt*scrollBar: false
# Clickable links
URxvt*perl-ext-common: default,matcher
URxvt*urlLauncher: firefox
URxvt*matcher.button: 1
```

Comment: Please post your .Xdefaults - it is impossible to provide any sensible suggestions without seeing what is currently in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that colour scheme, you could define a cursor colour that provided sufficient contrast, so that it would be readily visible in the window and also transparent enough to highlight the letter it is over.

Try: `URxvt.cursorColor: #666`

One other thing you might want to change: comments in this file are a `!` not a `#` - it could save you from some grief further down the track...